# Double quote string manipulation

Tags: python

I have some input data from ASCII files which uses double quote to encapsulate string as well as still use double quote inside those strings, for example:

```
"Reliable" "Africa" 567.87 "Bob" "" "" "" "S 05`56'21.844"" "No Shift"
```

Notice the double quote used in the coordinate.

So I have been using:

```
valList = shlex.split(line)
```

But shlex get's confused with the double quote used as the second in the coordinate.

I've been doing a find and replace on `'\"\"'` to `'\\\"\"'`. This of course turns an empty strings to `\""` as well so I do a find and replace on (this time with spaces) `' \\\"\" '` to `' \"\"" '`. Not exactly the most efficient way of doing it!

Any suggestions on handling this double quote in the coordinate?

Comment: Instead of fixing up the bad input data after the fact, you ought to have it generated with escape sequences from the get go.

Comment: You probably will need to do this manually, or if the format is too complicated use some parser like antlr.

Comment: Have you tried using other split methods?

Comment: @JohnKugelman would love to but unfortunately the world has bad developers and this source of data I can do nothing about apart from fix the bad data.

Comment: @Magitrek only string.split but then I have to do as much work as using shlex

Comment: I would probably preprocess the data with a very narrowly targeted regex that only fixes (escapes) the double quote in the coordinate column.

Comment: Is it true that double_quote-space-double_quote is always the ending and beginning double quotes and that all the others are internal?  That might help you.  (Then you would just need to deal with the very first one and very last one)

Comment: @jcfollower yes, I was thinking that, go through each double quote test before and end, I think the regex is a possible, could test if number exists before two double double quotes then turn the first double quote to an '\"'

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

I would treat this line of text as a `csv` file. Then according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) :

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"

Then all you would need to do is to add another `"` to your coordinates. So it would look like this `"S 05`56'21.844"""`(NOTE extra quote) Then you can use a standart`csv` module to break it apart and extract necessary information.

```
    >>> from StringIO import StringIO
    >>> import csv
    >>>
    >>> test = '''"Reliable" "Africa" 567.87 "Bob" "" "" "" "S 05`56'21.844""" "No Shift"'''
    >>> test_obj = StringIO(test)
    >>> reader = csv.reader(test_obj, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    >>> for i in reader:
    ...   print i
    ...
```

The output would be :

```
['Reliable', 'Africa', '567.87', 'Bob', '', '', '', 'S 05`56\'21.844"', 'No Shift']
```

Comment: This would still require a manual adding of the additional double quote right?  I'm after a python way of adding the additional double quote as there are many files (I have no influence over how these files are exported by the other software, different vendor)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with regexes, but this non-regex suggestion might help ...

```
INPUT = ('"Reliable" "Africa" 567.87 "Bob" "" "" "" "S 05`56'
         "'" 
         '21.844"" "No Shift"')


def main(input):
    output = input

    surrounding_quote_symbol = '<!>'

    if input.startswith('"'):        
        output = '%s%s' % (surrounding_quote_symbol, output[1:])
    if input.endswith('"'):
        output = '%s%s' % (output[:-1], surrounding_quote_symbol)

    output = output.replace('" ', '%s ' % surrounding_quote_symbol)
    output = output.replace(' "', ' %s' % surrounding_quote_symbol)
    print "Stage 1:", output

    output = output.replace('"', '\"')
    output = output.replace(surrounding_quote_symbol, '"')

    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = main(INPUT)
    print "End results:", output
```

Comment: There are no regexes here :-P